# How i can change the state of my button on my object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to change the value on my button. Basically , when i click on the button validate, the task goes to my column "tâche à faire" and the button is "en cours" .

When i click on this button, i want my task (with my const "switchencours") to switch to "encours" for "terminé" and moove to the column "tâches terminées"

For the moment, when i click on the button en cours, nothing moove, my value "etat" doesn't change.

Someone can help me with that ?

```
function Task() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ task: "", etat: "en cours" });

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const switchEnCours = () => {
    setTask({ ...task, etat: "terminé" });
  };

  const switchTerminé = () => {
    setTask({ ...task, etat: "supprimée" });
    setTodoList([...todoList, task]);
  };

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setTask({ ...task, task: e.target.value });
  };
  const AddTask = () => {
    setTodoList([...todoList, task]);

    console.log(todoList);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(todoList), [todoList]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleInput}></input>
      <button onClick={AddTask}>Valider</button>
      <div className="DivColonne">
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche à faire</h1>

          {todoList.map((insertTask, index) => {
            if (insertTask.etat === "en cours") {
              return (
                <div>
                  <p>{insertTask.task}</p>
                  <button onClick={switchEnCours}>{insertTask.etat}</button>
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              return <div></div>;
            }
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche en cours</h1>

          <div>
            {todoList.map((insert) => {
              if (insert.etat === "terminé") {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <p>{insert.task}</p>
                    <button onClick={switchTerminé}>{insert.etat}</button>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Tâches terminées</h1>

          <div>
            {todoList.map((done) => {
              if (done.etat === "supprimé") {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <p>{done.task}</p>
                    <p>{done.etat}</p>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Task;
```

Comment: can you pls add an example so I can help more.

Comment: Actually your setTask doesn't affect your todoList.task ! as you can see : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-7-usestate-forked-h9141?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Your `switchEnCours` function is setting the `task` sate , where as the the different columns `Tâche à faire`, `Tâche en cours` etc. uses the `todoList` state. In order for the changes to be reflected in different columns you need to set the new changes to `todoList` state. Please find the correct implementation below. I have made changes to your `switchEnCours` and `switchTerminé` functions.

```
function Task() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ task: "", etat: "en cours" });

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const switchEnCours = (taskToSwitch) => {
    setTodoList((todoList) =>
      todoList.map((item) =>
        item === taskToSwitch ? { ...item, etat: "terminé" } : item
      )
    );
  };

  const switchTerminé = (taskToSwitch) => {
    setTodoList((todoList) =>
      todoList.map((item) =>
        item === taskToSwitch ? { ...item, etat: "supprimé" } : item
      )
    );
  };

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setTask({ ...task, task: e.target.value });
  };
  const AddTask = () => {
    setTodoList([...todoList, task]);

    console.log(todoList);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(todoList), [todoList]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleInput}></input>
      <button onClick={AddTask}>Valider</button>
      <div className="DivColonne">
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche à faire</h1>

          {todoList.map((insertTask, index) => {
            if (insertTask.etat === "en cours") {
              return (
                <div>
                  <p>{insertTask.task}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => switchEnCours(insertTask)}>
                    {insertTask.etat}
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              return <div></div>;
            }
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche en cours</h1>

          <div>
            {todoList.map((insert) => {
              if (insert.etat === "terminé") {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <p>{insert.task}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => switchTerminé(insert)}>
                      {insert.etat}
                    </button>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Tâches terminées</h1>

          <div>
            {todoList.map((done) => {
              if (done.etat === "supprimé") {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <p>{done.task}</p>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Task;
```

You can also find the correct implementation in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-jackson-y9xtd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)